# ASM - math operations without FPU

Tags: assembly, floating-point, addition

I'm looking for a routine, which help me to do any of operation on floating point numbers (it can be addition), but without using Floating Point Unit (FPU).

I have to make a program, which compares time of doing operation without FPU and with FPU. Second part, with using FPU is done, but I can't find any good routine.

Comment: I'm sorry to be "that guy," but *why?* I guarantee you using a built-in FPU is going to be *much* faster than doing it yourself with integer operations. Is this homework or something? Otherwise save yourself the trouble...

Comment: Why not use [SoftFloat](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html)?

Comment: Also, a single "routine" to perform all possible operations on floating point numbers in software would be... well... rather large and complicated... That said, there are probably libraries out there to be found, and some compilers (at least `gcc`), given the right options, can simply generate non-FPU floating-point code for you...

Comment: @dvnrrs: It is program for my studies - it has to compare times. Everyone knows that FPU is faster, but I have to measure it.

Comment: Leeor - how can I use it in .asm files?

Comment: twalberg - I need only one. Addition/substraction/multiplication/division. You can choose one :-)

Comment: This is a rather complex thing to do, I find it hard to believe you need to write one for homework.  Use a library for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why people are all shocked about the complexity.
Addition, subtraction and multiplication are not terribly difficult.
You will need to split the numbers into sign, mantissa and exponent then use integer math to calculate the result and finally put it back into a float. I happen to have sample code for float multiplication (64 bit `GAS` syntax):

```
.globl main
main:
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq format1(%rip), %rdi
    leaq (%rsp), %rsi
    leaq 4(%rsp), %rdx
    xor %eax, %eax
    call scanf

    movl (%rsp), %eax           # x
    movl 4(%rsp), %ecx          # y

    movl %eax, %edx             # edx = x
    xorl %ecx, %eax             # sgn(x*y) = sgn(x) ^ sgn(y)
    andl $0x80000000, %eax      # eax has correct sign bit now
    movl %ecx, %esi             # esi = y
    shrl $23, %esi
    andl $0xff, %esi            # esi = exp(y)
    movl %edx, %edi             # edi = x
    shrl $23, %edi
    andl $0xff, %edi            # edi = exp(x)
    addl %esi, %edi             # exp(x*y) = exp(x) + exp(y)
    subl $0x7f+23, %edi         # subtract bias and mantissa bits

    andl $0x007fffff, %edx      # edx = man(x)
    andl $0x007fffff, %ecx      # ecx = man(y)
    orl $0x00800000, %ecx       # put implicit leading 1 bit
    orl $0x00800000, %edx       # to both mantissas
    imulq %rcx, %rdx            # man(x*y) = man(x) * man(y)
    bsrq %rdx, %rcx             # find first set bit
    subl $23, %ecx              # leave 23 bits
    shrq %cl, %rdx              # shift the rest out
    andl $0x007fffff, %edx      # chop off implicit leading 1 bit
    addl %ecx, %edi             # adjust the exponent by the bits shifted out

    shll $23, %edi              # shift exponent into position
    orl %edi, %eax              # put exponent into result
    orl %edx, %eax              # put mantissa into result

    movss (%rsp), %xmm0
    movss 4(%rsp), %xmm1
    movd %eax, %xmm2
    cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtss2sd %xmm1, %xmm1
    cvtss2sd %xmm2, %xmm2
    movl $3, %eax
    leaq format2(%rip), %rdi
    call printf

    addq $8, %rsp
    ret
.data
    format1: .asciz "%f %f"
    format2: .asciz "%f * %f = %f\n"
```

Special cases for zero, nan, inf, overflow and such are left as an excercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks :-) But do you have variant for 32 bit? And I'm wondering about FASM syntax, but if you have any other 32 bit, it will be enough for me.

Comment: The only 64 bit part (except the input and output that you don't need) is the 4 instructions beginning with the `imulq`. You should be able to rewrite that for 32 bit yourself, but keep in mind that the 64 bit multiply in 32 bit mode will use `edx`:`eax` so you will need a little shuffling.