# ASM (Gnu AS): How to split a FLOAT variable into parts?

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, gnu

I got a small problem: that I want to split a float variable into parts and then compute these parts (add / subtract etc.). My main problem is that I don't know how to get that splitted parts/variables from the `float` type variable. I want to operate on those parts using `rax` / `eax` registers and `b`,`c`,`d` etc.

Is there somebody who can help me to acquire some knowledge about this and eventually lead me to some code that can do the trick? One restriction of mine is: I can't operate on FPU commands.

Comment: Split? Into what parts? It would be helpful to elaborate on the desired splitting process. Bit by bit.

Comment: This is one [float format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). To split it up into its parts you will need AND and shift operations, not forgetting that the ms bit of the mantissa is implicit, ie, not coded.

Comment: OK then with what command i can get to the specific bit of xmm0 register or .float variable ?? How i can basicaly compute it, what method will give me a way to add 0.05 and 0.023 variables  ?? At first i thought ithat it is placed in memory like 32 bits for number and 32 for precision after coma.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21702808/547981) for an example.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i were looking for. I did some of this myself but my code didnt work properly for special cases, now i can update it :)